# Characters str.toLowerCase() on accent letters

Tags: javascript, translation

Will there ever be a use-case where accent letters will not allow lowercase conversions.

I've tested and have yet to come to a scenario where it broke but not very familiar with managing translated text in this manner.

I'm getting data from a web service that relies on string values, which are being translated into different languages. In order to leverage this data, I have to do string comparisons to append deeplinks to specific names/strings.

I'm aware, it's a terrible setup, but no way around it at this time.

Due to case-sensitivity and the fact that this web service is continually adjusted, e.g. "This Is A String" changed to "This is a String", I'm trying to lowercase these values prior to the check.

e.g.

```
const pendingTaskDeepLink,
  tasksPending = types.pendingTasks.list;

for (let prop in tasksPending ) {
  if (tasksPending.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {

    const task = tasksPending[prop],
      /** only two items returned in web service (where's the ID's!?) */
      name = task.taskName,
      count = task.taskCount;

    name = name.toLowerCase(); // can be translated into many languages

    /** English version of string being compared */
    if (name === 'activities pending action') pendingTaskDeepLink = '?params=' + encodeURIComponent('{"ssotarget":"ReviewActivities"}');

    pendingTasksMenu += '<li><a href="/#' + fundLink + pendingTaskDeepLink + '" class="sso-pending-task" target="_blank">' + name + ' <span class="label label-primary">' + count + '</span></a></li>';

  }
}
```

Comment: these downvotes with no reasons on SO drives me crazy. you don't understand the question so you downvote? Anyways i think for most accents it will work i just did `'ÃÁÀÊÉ'.toLowerCase()` and got "ãáàêé" in my browser console

Comment: Use `.toLocaleLowerCase()`?

Comment: @vlaz, that's even better

Comment: @vlaz Thanks! I haven't worked with internationalization much so wasn't aware there was a specific prototype method intended for this. (nor did I use the correct terminology to pull accurate search results) So much appreciated!